# How to structure Angular with Highcharts and lots of dynamic data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I know it's a bit difficult sometimes without having the code, but I wanted to check some ideas on how I could structure a code that is growing quite fast, and wanted to do it before it gets worse :)

For this, I'm using `Java(Spring)` as backend, `Angular` and `Highcharts`.

Basically it's a dashboard that contains some charts and are populated dynamically dependending on user selection. Its data is also auto-refreshed each 15 seconds.

I have a backend in `Java` in which I get this data.

In `Angular`, I have some functions in the controller to manipulate the data, create the highcharts, set the series, load user options and so on. Also there is a service that queries data and do some manipulation.

Now that this dashboard is working ok, I will need to do a similar dashboard, but with a different content / context but virtually, the same structure and functions.

So here's the thing.. today I have one service and one controller for all of this, and there a couple of DOM manipulations in the controller in order to make this work.

**Question**
Can you give me some ideas on how I could structure all this code?
I wanted to:

- Be able to test it quite easily
- Reuse this code for a similar dashboard
- Have an easier code to maintain (now there are many functions that have complex logic to handle data, handle refresh and it's quite difficult to maintain)

I was reading John Papa style guide, and thought now of two solutions but yet seem very ~*problematic*~:

1. Create a directive that would represent the chart, and therefore have quite heavy logic in order to retrieve data and all. I think it would be a bit difficult to test and not sure about performance.
2. Create a module called `Dashboard` and it would contain all these functions, but split up in many `mini-services` as opposed to only one. So one service would retrieve the data, other would handle events, other would create the Highcharts objects..

Can you help me out? If you have some links, books or anything that would help on this, I would really appreciate!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have done something similar in my recent project where i have 10 to 15 pages each heavily loaded with different kind of chart.

The easier and best approach i come up is with creating a common service for different chart and a common base chart directive to look for changes in chart data.

The basic structure of my chart service is something like below. Just for demonstration i am taking pie chart as a reference.

```
(function (angular) {
    var module = angular.module('pie-chart', ['my-project']);

   module.service('pieChartService', [
       'globalVariables', 'SharedDataService', '$q', '$filter', '$log', 'serverDataHelper',
       function (globalVariables, SharedDataService, $q, $filter, $log, serverDataHelper) {

           var getBaseChartData = function (chart) {

               var seriesObj = getSeriesObj(chart);

               var baseChartData = {
                   chart: {
                       type: 'pie',
                       width: 250 + 100 + 30,                      
                       height: 210,
                       style: {
                           fontFamily: "'Open Sans', sans-serif, arial;",
                       },
                       spacing: [0, 0, 0, 0]
                   },
                   title: {
                       text: ''
                   },
                   legend: {
                       align: 'right',
                       verticalAlign: 'middle',
                       layout: 'vertical',
                       itemMarginTop: 16,
                       useHTML: true, // in order to disable legend navigation
                       itemStyle: {
                           fontSize: '13px',
                           fontWeight: 'normal',
                           cursor: 'default'
                       },
                       symbolWidth: 13,
                       symbolHeight: 13,
                       symbolPadding: 11
                       width: 110,
                       y: -12
                   },
                   tooltip: {
                       backgroundColor: '#fff',
                       borderColor: '#ccc',
                       borderRadius: 3,
                       borderWidth: 1,
                   },
                   plotOptions: {
                       pie: {
                           showInLegend: true,
                           dataLabels: {
                               formatter: function () { return this.percentage > 0 ? $filter('number')(this.percentage, globalVariables.fractionSize) + '%' : ''; },
                               distance: -25,
                               color: 'white',
                               style: {
                                   fontSize: '14px',
                                   fontWeight: 'normal',
                                   textShadow: 'false'
                               }
                           },
                           center: [100, 90],
                           size: 180,
                           borderWidth: 3,
                           states: {
                               hover: {
                                   halo: {
                                       opacity: 0.75,
                                       size: 5
                                   },
                                   brightness: 0
                               }
                           },
                           point: {
                               events: {
                                   legendItemClick: function (event) { event.preventDefault(); }
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   },
                   series: seriesObj
               };
               return baseChartData;
           }

           var defaultChartSerieColors = [
               '#f8981d', //orange    
               '#6663ac', //purple 
               '#54b4c8', // blue 
               '#fecd08', // yellow 
               '#a3ca5f', // green 
               '#ef4036' // red 
           ];

           var getSeriesObj = function (chartObj) {
               var serie = {
                   data: [],
                   serverDateRanges: {
                       primary: {
                           startDate: undefined,
                           endDate: undefined
                       },
                       secondary: {
                           startDate: undefined,
                           endDate: undefined,
                       },
                   }
               };

               var series = [serie];

               jQuery.each(chartObj.Data, function (index, pointData) {

                   var point = {
                       name: pointData.Name,
                       y: pointData.Value,
                       color: defaultChartSerieColors[index],
                       Id: pointData.Id,
                       serverData: pointData
                   };
                   serie.data.push(point);
               });

               return series;
           }
           this.getPieChartData = function ($scope, url, params, chartDiff) {

               var pieChartDataPromise = serverDataHelper.getChartData(
                           url,
                           params);

               pieChartDataPromise.then(function (serverResponse) {
                   var pieChart = serverResponse.data;

                  var pieChartData = getBaseChartData(pieChart.Primary);

                   var chartData = jQuery.extend(true, {}, pieChartData);
                   chartData = jQuery.extend(true, chartData, chartDiff);

                   $scope.pieChartData = chartData;
               });

               return pieChartDataPromise;
           };
       }
    ]);
})(window.angular);
```

**serverDataHelper** : It is a common service for http calls.
**SharedDataService** : Service to store common data for whole application.

After putting above code to the separate file named pieChart.js, the controller code looks something like below.

```
(function () {
    var module = angular.module('social.module', [
        //dependancy
    ]);

    var urls = {
        getSocialChartUrl: 'api end point'        
    };

    var socialChartDataDiff = {
        chart: {
            height: 220,
            width: 600,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)'
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: true,
            x: -200,
            useHTML: true,
            labelFormatter: function () {
                return '<span class="legend-title">' + this.name + '</span>' + '<span class="legend-value"> (' + this.y + ')</span>';
            },
            itemStyle: {
                cursor: 'pointer'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                showInLegend: true,
                dataLabels: {
                    /*format: '{percentage:.2f}',*/
                    formatter: function () { return this.point.y; },
                    distance: -25,
                    color: 'white',
                    style: { "fontSize": "11px" }
                },
                borderWidth: 0,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        halo: {
                            opacity: 0.75,
                            size: 5
                        },
                        brightness: 0
                    }
                },
                point: {
                    events: {
                        event.preventDefault(); 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.key + ': ' + this.y;
            }
        }
    };

    module.controller('socialOnPageController', [
     '$scope', 'mcatSharedDataService', 'globalVariables', 'pieChartService', 'socialOnPageService', 'chartHelperService', '$q',
    function ($scope, mcatSharedDataService, globalVariables, pieChartService, socialOnPageService, chartHelperService, $q) {

            var params = {
                //params
            };

            var chartDataPromise = pieChartService.getPieChartData($scope, urls.getSocialChartUrl, params, socialChartDataDiff);

    }]);

})();
```

You need to add dependency of pieChartService in the controller.

**socialChartDataDiff** : You can change the default chart configuration here. In my case all the chart doesnt have same look in  terms of tooltip, legend and many more. In base pie chart implementation i am extending the default configuration with this chart difference. If all chart looks same no need to pass anything here.

My markup is something like below.

```
<mi-chart value="pieChartData" chart-obj="pieChartDataObj" is-fixed-width="true"></mi-chart>
```

The mi-chart is a directive to look for changes in base chart.

The code for mi-chart looks something like below which is common for all chart throughout my application.

```
(function () {

    var module = angular.module('mi-chart', []);

    module.directive('miChart', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div id="chartContainer" class="chartContainer"></div>',
            scope: {
                chartData: "=value",
                chartObj: "=?"
            },
            replace: true,
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $scope.$watch('chartData', function (value) {
                    if (!value) {
                        return;
                    }

                    $scope.chartData.chart.renderTo = $scope.chartData.chart.renderTo || $element[0];
                    $scope.chartObj = new Highcharts.Chart($scope.chartData);
                });
            }
        }
    }]);

})();
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for putting this together! Indeed the case is similar and this will help me a lot!